# jQuery Bootstrap multiple modals, how to hide active/top modal only

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've got a modal form that sometimes requires a second modal to be opened to set or display some data. I'm able to launch the first and second modals OK, but when I close the 'top' modal, both modals are hidden. Is it possible to hide one modal at a time?

Show Modal One:

```
$('#content').on('click', "a#AddItemModal", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('value');

    var val = '/AddItems/id:' + id;

    $('#addItemBody').load(val);
    $('#addItemModal').modal({});

});
```

Modal One:

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="addItemModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="addItemBody"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn"  data-dismiss="modal" id="good">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Show Modal Two:

```
$('#test_embed').click(function () {
        var val = $('#formEmbed').val();
        $('#myModalLabel').html('Embed Preview');
        $('#embedBody').html(val);
        $('#embedModal').modal({});
    });
```

Modal Two:

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="embedModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Embed Preview</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="embedBody"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you should manually close the Modal because when you click on the close button you fire a "close" event which hide all the modal. To manually close a modal, call `$('#addItemModal').modal('hide');`for the first modal and `$('#embedModal').modal('hide');`.

Now you can put a button in your modal that call these:

Modal One:

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="addItemModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    ...
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn"  data-number="1" id="good">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal Two:

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="embedModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    ...
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-number="2">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("button[data-number=1]").click(function(){
    $('#addItemModal').modal('hide');
});

$("button[data-number=2]").click(function(){
    $('#embedModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I have been looking for! It works perfectly and can be applied to several layers of modals. I love it, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I usually make sure that the second modal is not a child modal inside the parent one.
Because the `data-dismiss="modal"` closes the current modal and all parent modals.

so make if possible make it:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Model1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="Model2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
</div>
```

Not

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Model1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal fade" id="Model2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   </div>
</div>
```

Or I remove the `data-dismiss="modal"` and assign class "close" for example for the link or button i want to use to close modals then using one jquery event I can close/hide just the close button modal.

```
 $('#mycontainer').on('click', '.modal .close', function () {
        $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
```

Comment: I usually make sure that the second modal is not a child modal inside the parent one. Because the data-dismiss="modal" closes the current modal and all parent modals.
=> that's right, thank you

Comment: I take 2nd option,but still all modals are closed

Answer (score 0):

just append your modal to body - after modal created

`$('body').append('#addItemModal');`

now will closed only active top modal

Answer (score 0):

> One Modal and Three Tab

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="QualityControlMeasurementModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="min-width: 80rem;">    
        <div class="modal-content">    
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5>...</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group  row">
              <div class="row col-12"> 
                <div class="col">
                  <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-primary btn-lg ">...</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-success btn-lg">...</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <button type="button"  data-dismiss="modal" class="form-control close btn-lg btn btn-danger"
                    style="background-color: #cc0000;" >...</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
              </div>
              <hr>       
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

- Hide:(data-dismiss = modal)