# Close all other modals when a new one is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm opening modal using this javascript code:

```
$(".modal-wide").on("show.modal", function() {
  var height = $(window).height() - 200;
  $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
});
```

It opens up nicely, but when I open another one either from inside the old or whatever the case might be, it overlaps the old. I need it to close the other modal *(maybe have a "back" button but lets focus on the main problem first)*.

Here is a codepen.io link for a full example with the css and html I use:
http://codepen.io/Volcan3/pen/RpyRxd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Bootstrap multiple modals, how to hide active/top modal only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933424/jquery-bootstrap-multiple-modals-how-to-hide-active-top-modal-only)

Comment: @Martin check out my answer below. Just do simple change in html, no extra javascript . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below `javascript` code under your code.

You can see the change through the link [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/123/).

JAVASCRIPT-

```
$('a[data-toggle="modal"]').bind('click',function(){
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: I see it working in your fiddle, but I cant get it to work in my code? I added the bootstrap.js, and the jquery is already linked (as http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js)

Comment: nvm, works now. had to remove the jquery from the javascript tab. thanks for your help

Comment: @Martin my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Call this line before opening the modal2

```
$('#modal1').removeClass('in').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your codepen sample and it works:

```
$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){$('.fade.in[id^=modal]').last().siblings('.fade.in[id^=modal]').removeClass('in').hide();},300);
});
```

add it to the bottom of your js script

Comment: @Martin let me know if there was any other issue

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way, just add `data-dismiss="modal"` to `#modal2` anchor, no extra javascript:

```
<a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">modal 2</a>
```